# Why I can't edit login.blade.php (Laravel/Spark)?

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-spark

I'm trying to edit Spark's default login page.

At `Project/spark/src/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('spark::auth.login');
}
```

So I tried to edit `Project/spark/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php`:

```
<div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
```

to

```
<div class="panel-heading">ABC</div>
```

and saved. But no changes are shown.

Is this the right file? Is a cache problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 files named `login.blade.php` with identical contents but in different directories. (The structure is misleading)

The file which it contents are shown, and therefore should be edited, is:

`Project/resources/views/vendor/spark/auth/login.blade.php`